# Wrap text inside view without overflowing

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native.  I am trying to set the text in a view, but the text is overflowing outside the view like in the image below. Tried `flexWrap:'wrap` and `flexShrink:1` but it is also not working. I have implemented as follows:

[image]

```
 <View style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList
                data={this.state.data}
                renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigate('BlogDetails', item)}>
                        <Card style={{flexDirection:'row',flexShrink:1}}>
                            <CardSection>
                                <View style={styles.thumbnailContainerStyle}>
                                    <Image
                                        style={styles.thumbnailStyle}
                                        source={{ uri: item.imagepath }}
                                    />
                                </View>
                                <CardSection>
                                <View style={styles.headerContentStyle}>
                                    <Text numberOfLines={5} style={styles.headerTextStyle}>{item.news_title}</Text>
                                    {/* <Text>{item.blog_description}</Text> */}
                                </View>
                                </CardSection>

                            </CardSection>
                        </Card>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                )}

                keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            >

            </FlatList>
        </View>
```

My style :

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
    minHeight: 1,
    minWidth: 1,
},
thumbnailContainerStyle: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginRight: 10
},
headerContentStyle: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    flexWrap:'wrap',
    flexShrink:1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'flex-start'
},
thumbnailStyle: {
    width: 130,
    height: 130,
    resizeMode:"contain"
},
imageStyle: {
    height: 100,
    flex: 1,
    width: null
},
cardStyle:{
     width:'100%',
     height:200,
},
headerTextStyle:{
    fontSize:20,
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    flexShrink: 1

},
infoText: {
    fontSize: 14
}

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

Add `flexShrink:1` in parent wrapper and in text component do `flex:1 and flexWrap:'wrap'`

Comment: I just removed the CardSection and done as per advice and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

use only flexWrap : 'wrap' for wrap your text use this css for your view and text

```
headerContentStyle: {
  flexWrap : 'wrap'
},

headerTextStyle:{
   fontSize:20,
},
```

Comment: let me know if you still get any problem.